# Grouping data based on difference in days

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has 3 columns a subid , test,day. For each subject, I want to identify which tests happened within a time frame of x days and calculate max change in test value. Please see example below. For each subject and a given test ,I want to identify which tests happened within 3 days. so if we look at "Day" column, for the value =1 it wont have any groups as subsequent test was done 6 days after.  Values of Day=  10,7,8,9 should be identified as a group and the max change among these should be calculated. Similarly  Day = 12,11,10,9 should be identified as another group and the max change among these should be calculated. How can i do this using R. Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Try `which(diff(df$Day) <=3)` the expected output is not clear

Comment: If you are doing this grouped by 'Subjid', the 7:12 difference between adjacent elements are less than 3 similarly 1:2 for Subjid 2.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The *"within 3 days"* can be interpreted in different ways. For instance, if `001` had days 7 through 15, would it then be several summaries, with 7-12, 8-13, 9-14, and 10-15? Or would they all be grouped together still, because what you really need is *"a gap no more than 2 days"*?